# Orbeon 2017.2 CE: 'Error performing seach' received on loading /fr/orbeon/builder/summary page

Tags: orbeon, exist-db

I have installed exist-4.3.1 from exist.war and configured it to talk to Orbeon Forms 2017.1 CE.  I am able to save, load and publish forms.  However, when I view the Summary page to list all my forms, the "Error performing search" message pops up.
I have followed the instructions on setting up Form Runner and the Lucene  search facility (collection.xconf).

Do you know if there is any other configuration that is needed to fix the summary page?

Thank you,

Jake.

Comment: I'd recommend you start by checking your `orbeon.log`. You'll also find more about this on: https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/troubleshooting/orbeon-log. And you'll let me know what you find.

Comment: 2018-09-28 23:02:11,137 ERROR XFormsServer  - xf:message - Process failed with error for property: `oxf.fr.detail.process.after-controls.foreground.summary`

Comment: 2018-09-28 23:02:10,726 ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - xf:submission for submission id: search-submission, error code received when submitting instance: 400

Comment: I have noticed these 2 errors in the orbeon.log which are received after the search request is sent.

Comment: The process error was fixed in Orbeon Forms 2017.2.1, and it's probably not relevant. https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3517

Comment: As mentioned by @ebruchez, those errors are most likely not relevant to the issue you're seeing. Could you try doing item 4 [here](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/troubleshooting/orbeon-log), post the `orbeon.log` you get somewhere (e.g. as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/)), and link to it here?

Comment: Hi @jtb, if this is still a current issue for you, did you get a chance to reproduce the issue, and capture the `orbeon.log`, per my previous comment?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to reproduce it yet, but I will supply a snapshot of my `orbeon.log` as a Gist.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/coloneltravis/267dc09c3fb0cc1c23f359a4e1148b50